# Error details in embedded IronPython

Tags: c#, error-handling, ironpython

I'm executing IronPython in my application. A script produces an UnboundNameException with the message "name 'source' is not defined". Because the script is correct in my opinion I would need more error information, but I'm not able to get them from the exception. The exception itself seems not to contain any information about line number of the source of the exception or something like this.

I searched on Google, but all available information seems to be outdated. The Data dictionary of my exception is empty which means that Data["PythonExceptionInfo"] does not exist.

The file version of my IronPython assembly is 2.0.20209.0

Any hint how to get more error details?

cheers,
Achim

Comment: IMHO It seems that exception throwed when DLR tries to find a property in runtime,because it doesn't exist, so  try to insert a trace points in your program to got the breaking point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this question: [Getting traceback information from IronPython exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465262/getting-traceback-information-from-ironpython-exceptions)

That will tell you how you can format the exception (and in a general way that's not going to become outdated).  That should work w/ IronPython 2.0 - 2.7.