# How to get the offending line when using IronPython with C#/.NET as host, on a runtime error?

Tags: .net, python, exception, runtime

Confused by the title? Let me explain:
I do execute a python script, within a .NET process (my C# application being the host), using IronPython:

```
ScriptEngine python = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource pyFromFileSource = python.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script);
CompiledCode pyFromFileCode = pyFromFileSource.Compile();
ScriptRuntime runtime = engine.Runtime;
ScriptScope scope = runtime.CreateScope(); //get a scope where we put in the stuff from the host
scope.SetVariable("lab", this); //allow usage of this class in the script
script.Execute(scope);
```

The code shown above is running in a background thread (using the `Task` class). The script contains an error, which causes an `IronPython.Runtime.Exceptionis.TypeErrorException` to bubble up. I can catch this, and get the message. 

**But how to get the script line or line number that causes the exception?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can can call PythonOps.GetDynamicStackFrames on the exception and get the line numbers from the DynamicStackFrame objects.

Comment: Works great, thanks. For anyone else looking for it, `PythonOps` is in `IronPython.Runtime.Operations`.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1469456/24874) provides a means to format an exception caught from IronPython code into a string that contains more useful information such as line numbers and the Python call stack:

```
engine.GetService<ExceptionOperations>().FormatException(exception);
```